# Permission Error while Downloading from Mega.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Download File from Mega using mega.py

I'm trying to download a file from my Megadrive using mega.py module

while running the code as specified in mega module home url

I'm getting a Permission error as specified below

Code:

```
from mega import Mega


mega = Mega()
email ="example@example.com"
password ="xxxxxxxxxx"
m = mega.login(email, password)

filename = "filename.jpg"

file = m.find(filename)
m.download(file)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_d6ozyjm' -> 'filename.jpg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Mega.py", line 14, in <module>
    m.download(file)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 564, in download
    return self._download_file(file_handle=None,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 745, in _download_file
    shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 821, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_d6ozyjm'
```

Comment: If you check the issue page on github developers already know about this : https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py/issues/18
I just see that the problem in code is that they use `os.shutil.move` which tries to move open file but this is wrong, because they should first close the file before moving it

Comment: and also check this PR, someone already proposed solution 
https://github.com/odwyersoftware/mega.py/pull/27/commits/5fffdd00da651f9eb4e52dbbd4e8da196b50ca5a

Comment: solution in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465210/problem-downloading-mega-files-with-python

Answer (score 2):

I'm new in stackoverflow, I don't know and how to mark duplicated questions or things like that. Just want to help because I had that problem.

This is a duplicated question that already has a right answer:
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465437/14104956`

To put it faster, here's the answer, hope it helps you:

find the file path with `pip show mega.py`

Open the file

Goto line 745 where the line `shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path) is`.

Add `temp_output_file.close()`  right above it.

Save & try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `try/except` to handle that:

```
try:
    m.download(file)
except PermissionError:
    pass
```

this works with multiple files, loops, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other guy said, you need to edit the mega.py path file and probably Tenacity/Asyncio. [If you are lazy, I made an script that automatically patch the files and it makes backups for the modified files]

Fix for `mega.py`

1. [Infinite downloads/Error with access] Add `temp_output_file.close()` above `shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)`

After make that you now should get other error, the lastest version of python have problems using `Tenacity/Asyncio`, so when you try to import mega.py you get an error, it should be fixed finding `Tenacity` directory and find the file named `_asyncio.py`

Fix for `_asyncio.py`, you will need to update some code

1. Find and replace `@asyncio.coroutine` with `#@asyncio.coroutine`
2. Find `def call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):` and replace it with `async def call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):`
3. Find `result = yield from fn(*args, **kwargs)`
   and replace it with `result = await fn(*args, **kwargs)`
4. Find `yield from self.sleep(do)` and replace it with `await self.sleep(do)`

The script that fix that issue among others for python 3.10+
https://github.com/N1xUser/mega.py-FIX - The backups are made and saved on the same directory of `mega.py` and `_asyncio.py` with the name `_asyncio_backup.py` and `mega_backup.py`
I hope it works for you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34941403)

Comment: Oh, sorry, im new here ;D

Comment: Now i made a more completed answer