# Problem downloading MEGA files with python

Tags: python, url, download, save, temporary-files

I am trying to download a file from my MEGA account using the following code from the `mega.py` library of Python:

```
from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()
m = mega.login('example@example.com', 'example')
file = m.find('example.txt')
m.download(file, 'D:\\Desktop')
```

However, it is always returning:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Programas\aNaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The file is already being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\vrida\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_xdste432' -> 'example.txt'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-c3f75106fafb>", line 1, in <module>
    m.download(file)

  File "D:\Programas\aNaconda\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 564, in download
    return self._download_file(file_handle=None,

  File "D:\Programas\aNaconda\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py", line 745, in _download_file
    shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)

  File "D:\Programas\aNaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 803, in move
    os.unlink(src)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The file is already being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\vrida\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\megapy_example'
```

Actually when I enter in the folder (*C:\Users\vrida\AppData\Local\Temp*) I find a temporary file like the one I'm wanting to download but named *megapy_example*.

I saw that the following site has a discussion to solve the problem:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/mw6is2/download_file_from_mega_using_megapy/

asking to add the following lines to the code:

```
try:
      m.download(file, 'D:\\Desktop')
except PermissionError:
      continue
```

In my case, the *continue* command wasn't working so I simply put in the *pass* command. The code runs, but I don't know if the file is really saved or not.

Could someone please help me? I really need to download the files and save them.

If it doesn't work through the `mega.py` library, you guys would somehow know how to download from the public link like this by Python:
[https://mega.co.nz/#!cSZCELDb!5O57KMVMIgrPiH5fnaefWeNPDqoDWzGbY-sZkdTUdNk](http://%20https://mega.co.nz/#!cSZCELDb!5O57KMVMIgrPiH5fnaefWeNPDqoDWzGbY-sZkdTUdNk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in the library, it's not closing the file before moving it. You could fix the bug by editing the source code:

1. Open the file at `D:\Programas\aNaconda\lib\site-packages\mega\mega.py`
2. Goto line `745` where the line `shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)` is.
3. Add `temp_output_file.close()` right above it.
4. Save & try again.

Answer (score 0):

-> Now with the lastest version of python more erros appear, probably becouse of the use of Tenacity/Asyncio, this mayh help

Like the other guy said, you need to edit the mega.py path file and probably Tenacity/Asyncio. [If you are lazy, I made an script that automatically patch the files and it makes backups for the modified files]

Fix for `mega.py`

1. [Infinite downloads/Error with access] Add `temp_output_file.close()` above `shutil.move(temp_output_file.name, output_path)`

After make that you now should get other error, the lastest version of python have problems using `Tenacity/Asyncio`, so when you try to import mega.py you get an error, it should be fixed finding `Tenacity` directory and find the file named `_asyncio.py`

Fix for `_asyncio.py`, you will need to update some code

1. Find and replace `@asyncio.coroutine` with `#@asyncio.coroutine`
2. Find `def call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):` and replace it with `async def call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):`
3. Find `result = yield from fn(*args, **kwargs)`
   and replace it with `result = await fn(*args, **kwargs)`
4. Find `yield from self.sleep(do)` and replace it with `await self.sleep(do)`

The script that fix that issue among others for python 3.10+
https://github.com/N1xUser/mega.py-FIX - The backups are made and saved on the same directory of `mega.py` and `_asyncio.py` with the name `_asyncio_backup.py` and `mega_backup.py`
I hope it works for you